# Shorten URL with Regex

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Here's an example URL to a user profile on my site: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/overview/showuserprofile/user`

I want it to be:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/user`

This is what I have for rewrite rules:

```
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /php-login/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That gets rid of the `.php` at the end.

I've also tried adding

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=/overview/showuserprofile/$1 [QSA,L]`

But the URL would change and not any of the pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to figure out how to differentiate user pages from other pages.  Your rewrite expression `^(.+)$` matches all the pages on the site except for the home page.    You will need to limit this so that it doesn't match other pages including `index.php`.

One way of doing so would be to only allow user pages to use lower case letter with no punctuation.  Then it wouldn't match `index.php` due to the period.  The rewrite rule for that  would be:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?url=/overview/showuserprofile/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Another way to do it would be to check that there isn't a real file with that name as a rewrite condition using the instructions here: http://www.harecoded.com/apache-rewritecond-f-check-file-exists-solution-2246468

Comment: So by doing that and merging my other solution together they should work? So something like this? `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?url=/overview/showuserprofile/$1 [QSA,L]`